# Python Kivy slide screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have this program:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout



class Basics(App):
    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()

if __name__=="__main__":
    Basics().run()
```

And basics.kv file:

```
<Button>
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.2

<FloatLayout>
    Button:
        id: btn1
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0.8}
        text: "First Button"
    Button:
        id: btn2
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0.6}
        text: "Second Button"
    Button:
        id: btn3
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0.4}
        text: "Third Button"
    Button:
        id: btn4
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0.2}
        text: "Fourth Button"
    Button:
        id: btn5
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0}
        text: "Fifth button"
    Button:
        id: btn6
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":-0.2}
        text: "Sixth button"
```

And I get this output:
[image]

And that's ok, but I want to slide to the sixth button, without leaving the screen. Is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [ScrollView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#module-kivy.uix.scrollview).

Comment: Oh, nice, exactly what I was looking for, thank you